# Function behaves badly when passing dynamically allocated pointer

Tags: c++, dynamic, shuffle

I have this function

```
void shuffle_array(int* array, const int size){
  /* given an array of size size, this is going to randomly
   * attribute a number from 0 to size-1 to each of the
   * array's elements; the numbers don't repeat */
  int i, j, r;
  bool in_list;
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    in_list = 0;
    r = mt_lrand() % size; // my RNG function
    for(j = 0; j < size; j++)
      if(array[j] == r){
    in_list = 1;
    break;
      }
    if(!in_list)
      array[i] = r;
    else
      i--;
  }
}
```

When I call this function from

```
int array[FIXED_SIZE];
shuffle_array(array, FIXED_SIZE);
```

everything goes all right and I can check the shuffling was according to expected, in a reasonable amount of time -- after all, it's not that big of an array (< 1000 elements).

However, when I call the function from

```
int *array = new int[dynamic_size];
shuffle_array(array, dynamic_size);
[...]
delete array;
```

the function loops forever for no apparent reason. I have checked it with debugging tools, and I can't say tell where the failure would be (in part due to my algorithm's reliance on random numbers).

The thing is, it doesn't work... I have tried passing the array as `int*& array`, I have tried using `std::vector<int>&`, I have tried to use `random_shuffle` (but the result for the big project didn't please me).

Why does this behavior happen, and what can I do to solve it?

Comment: You might do it as a challenge, but consider that there are also standard library functions for your problem ;)

Comment: Are you confident on the correctness of your algorithm?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why i-- is required in the code when the outer for-loop requires i to be incremented.

Comment: @Marian, I don't think so. `i--` happens right before `i++`, so at worst, `i` stays the same across iterations.

Comment: Are you initializing `array` in your first case? Seems to me your code will loop forever if the last element in array contains a value from 0 to size - 1 as there will never be a new value to choose for the last item. Note: This will always be the case for a zero initialized array.

Comment: @SouravGhosh indeed, but maybe C programmers can help, since almost all of the features here described are present in both languages. The new would become a malloc() or something. Please tell if it's not appropriate to use this tag.

Comment: @MohitJain yes, the algorithm is correct -- perhaps not efficient, but guaranteed to finish. We have n random numbers to put in n elements, the right one has to come out some time, and it does in the first case.

Comment: Are FIXED_SIZE and dynamic_size equal?

Comment: The `i--` makes the loop run again for the same value of `i`, thus giving a new chance to pick the element.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I would like to see options from the standard library... I tried `random_shuffle` but I didn't like the results, and all the overhead introduced looked unnecessary when I had a working function... besides, I'd like to have some control over my RNG, which is possible with std library, but maybe too much of a hassle if this one works.

Comment: @Dawid they are hypothetical, but yes, I have tried changing code manually to a constant and allowing the program to calculate dynamic_size, and the dynamic case didn't work.

Comment: @vitaoma, You should prefer `std::shuffle` to `std::random_shuffle` (which will be removed soon). And I don't see what hassle or overhead you're talking about. It's a one-line function call that is familiar to C++ developers everywhere and you give it the RNG as an argument. [This reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) even has some test code you can run and play around with right there.

Comment: For options in the standard library, see @chris 's answer and the given link for examples. Regarding performance, the most contributes to the random generator. You might select one carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that `array` is uninitialized in your first example. If you are using Visual Studio debug mode, Each entry in `array` will be set to all 0xCC (for "created"). This is masking your actual problem (see below).

When you use `new int[dynamic_size]` the array is initialized to zeros. This then causes your actual bug.

Your actual bug is that you are trying to add a new item only when your array doesn't already contain that item and you are looking through the *entire array* each time, however if your last element of your array is a valid value already (like 0), your loop will never terminate as it always finds 0 in the array and has already used up all of the other numbers.

To fix this, change your algorithm to only look at the values that you have put in to the array (i.e. up to `i`).

Change

```
for(j = 0; j < size; j++)
```

to

```
for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

Comment: Thank you. This works! However it introduces some artifacts in the shuffler... I'd better check some solutions in the standard library, as others recommended.

Comment: Yes definitely, the standard library is the way to go if you aren't using this as a learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that the problem lies with the way the array is initialized and the line:

```
r = mt_lrand() % size; // my RNG function
```

If the dynamically allocated array has been initialized to `0` for some reason, your code will always get stack when filling up the last number of the array.

I can think of the following two ways to overcome that:

1. You make sure that you initialize `array` with numbers greater than or equal to `size`.

   ```
   int *array = new int[dynamic_size];
   for ( int i = 0; i < dynnamic_size; ++i )
      array[i] = size;
   shuffle_array(array, dynamic_size);
   ```
2. You can allows the random numbers to be between `1` and `size` instead of between `0` and `size-1` in the loop. As a second step, you can subtract `1` from each element of the array.

   ```
   void shuffle_array(int* array, const int size){
      int i, j, r;
      bool in_list;
      for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
         in_list = 0;

         // Make r to be betwen 1 and size
         r = rand() % size + 1;
         for(j = 0; j < size; j++)
            if(array[j] == r){
               in_list = 1;
               break;
            }
         if(!in_list)
         {
            array[i] = r;
         }

         else
            i--;
      }

      // Now decrement the elements of array by 1.
      for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
         --array[i];

         // Debugging output
         std::cout << "array[" << i << "] = " << array[i] << std::endl;
      }
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing C code with C++ memory allocation routines of new and delete. Instead stick to pure C and use malloc/free directly.

```
   int *array = malloc(dynamic_size * sizeof(int));
   shuffle_array(array, dynamic_size);
   [...]
   free(array);
```

On a side note, if you are allocating an array using the new[] operator in C++, use the equivalent delete[] operator to properly free up the memory. Read more here - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new[]/